# How to beat Cerulean Gym 2 in Pokemon Tower Defense?

Tags: pokemon-tower-defense

Since there is only two spots for your Pokemon, and Kyogre uses the move sleep to get more health, is it even possible to beat this level? Or is their a strategy to beat it?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll have to train your Pokémon, when kyoger use rest it also sleep for a while. Try to attack it while it’s sleeping.